# Editing PDF from Java Using PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, edit, pdfbox

I am currently getting a page from a PDF and then trying to edit that particular page.
When i do the edit it is not saving within the PDF itself.

This is my code could someone please help.

```
PDPage page = (PDPage) allPages.get(f);
System.out.println(page);
PDRectangle pageSize = page.findMediaBox();
float stringWidth = font.getStringWidth( "AAA" );
float centeredPosition = (pageSize.getWidth() - (stringWidth*fontSize)/1000f)/2f;

PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(pdoc,page,true,false);

contentStream.beginText();
contentStream.setFont( font, fontSize );
//contentStream.addLine(700, 700, 700, 1000);
contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(0 , 0);
contentStream.drawString( "AAA" );
contentStream.endText();
contentStream.close();

pdoc.save("C:/1/1.pdf");
pdoc.close();
```

Comment: Do you really want to save it to `c:\1\1.pdf` (in folder `1` in `c:\ `)?

Comment: not necessary i was only testing that out but the problem is than when i do the save and go to 1.pdf i find that the AAA is not being added to the very bottom of the page at location 0 , 0
And when i change the PDPageContentStream and change the true to false i get that the page is overwritten with AAA

Comment: I have added for you in another question of yours code that inserts the "AAA" without overriding the page so I wonder why you come and post this question again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is with which I am doing this is correct.

The problem is not the code but the way the pdfs are being generated are at a Version 1.2.
I would need to be able know what I can do to alter PDFs that are one V 1.2

Answer (score 0):

please use/update below code

```
contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(
                document, page, true, true);
```

Its working for me

Comment: There actually are multiple issues in the op's code, and the 1.2 he chose to blame in his answer most likely was not the issue. But I doubt answering this old question will lead to anything.