# Java, edit pdf exist text with PDFBox

Tags: pdfbox

i trying edit text with library PDFBox and don't no how. I do not know how to get stream of individual text objects, so I could edit the text and or color.

Any idea, example?
Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7269257/editing-pdf-from-java-using-pdfbox

Comment: I found this, but there are just add text. Not edit. In library is class PDFTextStripper and work, but it extract just text, without style, etc... And i need edit the exist text.

Comment: Tricky. You'd have to look at the content stream and then make changes there.... so see what I mean, open your PDF with PDFDebugger (doesn't support editing) and look at "contents", then look at "operator summary" in the PDF 32000 specification to see what the operators mean.

Answer (score 1):

I found editing text in *pdf* is not reliable, so try to clear the text with a `rectangle` (white/background color fill) and write the new text in the cleared position. Here is a sample code.

```java
//to add a link in footer
//to replace a text
//to replace a link/url/href
public static void editTextorUrl(String inputFile, String outputFile)
        throws IOException, COSVisitorException {
    // the document
    PDDocument doc = null;
    try {
        System.out.println(inputFile);
        doc = PDDocument.load(inputFile);
        List pages = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
        for (int i = 0; i < pages.size(); i++) {

            float inch = 72;
            PDGamma colourRed = new PDGamma();
            colourRed.setR(1);
            PDGamma colourBlue = new PDGamma();
            colourBlue.setB(1);
            PDGamma white = new PDGamma();
            white.setR(1);
            white.setB(1);
            white.setG(1);

            PDBorderStyleDictionary borderThick = new PDBorderStyleDictionary();
            borderThick.setWidth(inch / 12); // 12th inch
            PDBorderStyleDictionary borderThin = new PDBorderStyleDictionary();
            borderThin.setWidth(inch / 72); // 1 point
            PDBorderStyleDictionary borderULine = new PDBorderStyleDictionary();
            borderULine.setStyle(PDBorderStyleDictionary.STYLE_UNDERLINE);
            borderULine.setWidth(inch / 72); // 1 point

            PDPage page = (PDPage) pages.get(i);
                    PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA;

            PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(
                    doc, page, true, false);
            contentStream.setNonStrokingColor(Color.WHITE);
            contentStream.fillRect(55, 27, 144, 17);
            contentStream.setNonStrokingColor(Color.BLUE);
            contentStream.beginText();
            contentStream.setFont(font, 11);
            contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(55, 37);
            contentStream.drawString("www.loasoftwares.com"); //text to be replaced

            contentStream.endText();
            contentStream.setLineWidth(inch / 300);
            contentStream.setStrokingColor(Color.BLUE);
            contentStream.drawLine(55, 34, 188, 34);
            contentStream.close();

            PDAnnotationLink txtLink = new PDAnnotationLink();
            PDRectangle position = new PDRectangle();
            position.setLowerLeftX(55);
            position.setLowerLeftY(27);
            position.setUpperRightX(188);
            position.setUpperRightY(50);
            txtLink.setRectangle(position);

            // add an action
            PDActionURI action = new PDActionURI();
            action.setURI("www.loasoftwares.com");
            txtLink.setBorderStyle(borderULine);
            txtLink.setAction(action);
            txtLink.setColour(white);

            page.getAnnotations().add(txtLink);
        }
        doc.save(outputFile);
    } finally {
        if (doc != null) {
            doc.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While it is true that actually editing text in a PDF is difficult in general, simply covering it with a white rectangle is not a really good idea in general either: the text is still accessible via copy&paste, and the white might stand out on a non-pure-white background.

Answer (score 0):

### Remark:

It works under specific circumstances (ASCII'ish font encodings + pretty long string arguments)

```java
/**
 * This is an example that will replace a string in a PDF with a new one.
 *
 * The example is taken from the pdf file format specification.
 *
 * @author <a href="mailto:ben@benlitchfield.com">Ben Litchfield</a>
 * @version $Revision: 1.3 $
 */
public class ReplaceString {
    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public ReplaceString() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * Locate a string in a PDF and replace it with a new string.
     *
     * @param inputFile The PDF to open.
     * @param outputFile The PDF to write to.
     * @param strToFind The string to find in the PDF document.
     * @param message The message to write in the file.
     *
     * @throws IOException If there is an error writing the data.
     * @throws COSVisitorException If there is an error writing the PDF.
     */
    public void doIt( String inputFile, String outputFile, String strToFind,  String message)
        throws IOException, COSVisitorException {
        // the document
        PDDocument doc = null;
        try
        {
            doc = PDDocument.load( inputFile );
            List pages = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
            for( int i=0; i<pages.size(); i++ )
            {
                PDPage page = (PDPage)pages.get( i );
                PDStream contents = page.getContents();
                PDFStreamParser parser = new PDFStreamParser(contents.getStream());
                parser.parse();
                List tokens = parser.getTokens();
                for( int j=0; j<tokens.size(); j++ )
                {
                    Object next = tokens.get( j );
                    if( next instanceof PDFOperator )
                    {
                        PDFOperator op = (PDFOperator)next;
                        //Tj and TJ are the two operators that display
                        //strings in a PDF
                        if( op.getOperation().equals( "Tj" ) )
                        {
                            //Tj takes one operator and that is the string
                            //to display so lets update that operator
                            COSString previous = (COSString)tokens.get( j-1 );
                            String string = previous.getString();
                            string = string.replaceFirst( strToFind, message );
                            previous.reset();
                            previous.append( string.getBytes("ISO-8859-1") );
                        }
                        else if( op.getOperation().equals( "TJ" ) )
                        {
                            COSArray previous = (COSArray)tokens.get( j-1 );
                            for( int k=0; k<previous.size(); k++ )
                            {
                                Object arrElement = previous.getObject( k );
                                if( arrElement instanceof COSString )
                                {
                                    COSString cosString = (COSString)arrElement;
                                    String string = cosString.getString();
                                    string = string.replaceFirst( strToFind, message );
                                    cosString.reset();
                                    cosString.append( string.getBytes("ISO-8859-1") );
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                //now that the tokens are updated we will replace the
                //page content stream.
                PDStream updatedStream = new PDStream(doc);
                OutputStream out = updatedStream.createOutputStream();
                ContentStreamWriter tokenWriter = new ContentStreamWriter(out);
                tokenWriter.writeTokens( tokens );
                page.setContents( updatedStream );
            }
            doc.save( outputFile );
        }
        finally
        {
            if( doc != null )
            {
                doc.close();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This will open a PDF and replace a string if it finds it.
     * <br />
     * see usage() for commandline
     *
     * @param args Command line arguments.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ReplaceString app = new ReplaceString();
        try
        {
            if( args.length != 4 )
            {
                app.usage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.doIt( args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3] );
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * This will print out a message telling how to use this example.
     */
    private void usage()
    {
        System.err.println( "usage: " + this.getClass().getName() +
            " <input-file> <output-file> <search-string> <Message>" );
    }
}
```

Comment: This is well intended, but read this: https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/migration.html "Why was the ReplaceText example removed?"

Comment: Sure, they removed ReplaceText example because this method is not working in all possible siruations, but ... for many number of users there is need for example that works in particular situation, as mine, for example, I need to change part number in printable PDF file everytime new order is received, instead of editing in Illustrator, I simply use simple java program that makes it perfectly, again, i dont intend to use it in every pdf file, only customized for this code.

Comment: Your answer would be greatly improved by adding a remark making clear that the code will only work under very specific circumstances (ASCII'ish font encodings plus pretty long string arguments).