# How to edit text in pdf preserving format of all textual and non-textual content?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I want to edit text in pdf file. Example :- If my PDF is having text as 'HELLO WORLD' then I want to encrypt it using one custom encryption algorithm to "GDKKN VNQKC" preserving font and location of text on page.
To encrypt it correctly I need to know what character is in the file and then apply my encryption algorithm on that and then write it in file in place of original character
How can I achieve this if it is even achievable using Apache PDFBox java library.

I have found that TJ operator is used to display text in pdf. I am parsing ContentStream for page and getting TJ token. When I am calling COSString.getSTring() from COSString received from TJ it shows me some random characters because this string is encoded in font. Now I have to find out how to get real character from this encoded value from Font and then encrypt it and encode encrypted character using Font and replace original character with encrypted one.

I have got this understanding from this posts [https://stackoverflow.com/a/47850848/22290633](https://stackoverflow.com),[https://stackoverflow.com/a/52586830/22290633](https://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: *"To encrypt it correctly I need to know what character is in the file"* - you cannot count on knowing that. The "text" drawing instructions use character codes in arbitrary encodings, encodings that don't need to have anything to do with standard encodings, e.g. the first glyph used on a given page might have the code 1, the second glyph code 2, etc etc. And there doesn't need to be any map to resolve that. And even if there is such a map, it may map different glyphs to the same Unicode character. Also there may be single glyphs representing ligatures, i.e. multiple characters, etc.

Comment: Hi  @mkl, Sorry for responding late. I am trying to follow your suggestions in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47850848/22290633 . In this answer you have given 5 steps to read and edit text in pdf at the end of the answer.  My current code is same as in this question : https://stackoverflow.com/q/60631596 . help me to figure out where I am going wrong.

Comment: *"Sorry for responding late. I am trying to follow your suggestions in this answer"* - Actually I there already said what I have said in my first comment here: *Each font in PDFs can use a different encoding for its strings, and these encodings don't even need to be standard encodings, they may be ad-hoc encodings created on the fly by the PDF creator program.* In that case without mappings to Unicode in the font object, it is very difficult to implement the step *decode the string contents according to the information in the font.*